# How can I implement multiple cucumber tags in behave?

Tags: python, selenium, cucumber, python-behave

I have to add the functionality for my tests to be able to run with different user roles in behave python selenium.
I have 2 user roles

1. Admin user
2. Non-Admin User

with 2 different credentials

now I thought with the help of tags I would be able to do it.
In total there are 30 feature files. I want all 30 feature files to run for admin and 20 feature files for non admin user.
I want tags to have additional functionality like for each tag the creds will be different.
For eg:
@admin.user
so for this tag the creds will be different
@nonadmin.user
the creds will be diff here as-well

I did add tags in the start of the feature file. and calls it in the command but it isn't working. Do I have to define the tags somewhere else other than the feature file?

Note: I want to use multiple tags for example @browser.firefox and @admin.user

behave --tags=@expert.user

I have installed:
pip install cucumber-tag-expressions

versions:
selenium=3.141.0
behave=1.2.6

Comment: I'm familiar with pytest-bdd not behave (but seems similar), based on the [docs](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gherkin.html?highlight=tags#controlling-your-test-run-with-tags) it seems like you just need to remove the `@` in your command. If that doesn't work, can you add a minimum reproducible example of code?

Comment: Hi, I have removed the @ in my command. 1 test failed and other skipped. There is one other tag @extension.chrome that has to be included in the tag.
So I ran this command:
`behave -tags=extension_chrome -tags=admin_user`
Its skipping all my tests. nothing is being executed.